# How can I implement a swipe left/right in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin Android.
I would like to implement a swipe left/right in a Linear Layout.

So for example:

- When swipping left --> method "Open()"
- When swipping right --> methode "Close()"

My code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/reddoor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgDoor"
    android:layout_marginTop="50px"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="fill"
    android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Open"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnOpenDoor" />
<Button
    android:text="Close"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnCloseDoor" />
```

How do I implement this? I searched but I just found something for Xamarin.Forms but I need Xamarin.Android. Can someon help pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you want to implement swipe function in xamarin.android, I do one sample that you can take a look:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="swap"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

 private Button btn1;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        btn1.SetOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this));

    }

  public class OnSwipeTouchListener : Java.Lang.Object , View.IOnTouchListener
{
    private  GestureDetector gestureDetector;
   public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx)
    {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        return gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);
    }
}
public class GestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    private static  int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static  int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;
    public override bool OnFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        // TODO
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            float diffY = e2.GetY() - e1.GetY();
            float diffX = e2.GetX() - e1.GetX();
            if (Math.Abs(diffX) > Math.Abs(diffY))
            {
                if (Math.Abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.Abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
                {
                    if (diffX > 0)
                    {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            else if (Math.Abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.Abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
            {
                if (diffY > 0)
                {
                    onSwipeBottom();
                }
                else
                {
                    onSwipeTop();
                }
                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _ = exception.StackTrace;
        }
        return result;

    }
    public void onSwipeRight()
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "right", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
    public void onSwipeLeft()
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "left", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
    public void onSwipeTop()
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "top", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
    public void onSwipeBottom()
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "up", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }


}
```

The Screenshot:

[image]